# Is there a work-around to deal with columns in a data.table that begin with a number?

Tags: r, data.table

I have this data.table:

```
example<-structure(list(`3M` = c(-0.38802, 1.20386, -22.14071), `CAR` = c(0.4537, 1.84032, -19.97575), CAB = c(0.44547,1.83358, -19.99101)), .Names = c("3M", "CAR","CAB"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,-3L))
```

I can do

```
example[,CAR]
[1]   0.45370   1.84032 -19.97575
```

which is what I expect.

If I do

```
example[,3M]
Error: unexpected symbol in "example[,3M"
```

which is not what I wanted.  Is there a way around this besides renaming it or quoting it and using `WITH=FALSE`.

Comment: nope, variables in R cannot start with a digit

Comment: Pick better names! `names(example) <- gsub('([[:digit:]])','v\\1',names(example))`.

Comment: @Frank the names come from a database and there are 1000s of them.  If I change the names of them then it'll be tougher to display the end result.  Anyway, Ananda's suggestion of using a backtick will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your last sentence, I assume you're looking for an alternative to using:

```
> example[,"3M"]
          3M
1:  -0.38802
2:   1.20386
3: -22.14071
```

In this case, if you want a vector as the output, you should be able to use backticks (which is still a bit of a drag, but works):

```
> example[,`3M`]
[1]  -0.38802   1.20386 -22.14071
```

Comment: The backtick will work.  My main aversion to the first option is that I can't then do formula's in the `J`.  With the backtick I can so it'll work well.  I took it a step further if you do `example[,list(\`3M\`)]` you can still get a data.table result.